# Should we really use chef to manage the sudoers file?

Tags: linux, chef-infra, sudo, system-administration, sudoers

This is my question. I am worried that if Chef breaks something in the sudoers file, probably by a Chef user using the cookbook incorrectly, then the server will be entirely inaccessible.

I would hate for us to completely lose a production server for a customer because we messed up the sudoers file and can no longer ssh into the box.

Comment: Just set up Chef to run as root periodically in a cronjob (chef_client cookbook can do that for you). Hence if you break it in the cookbook, fix it in the cookbook and at next run Chef will fix the files.

Comment: checkout [`sudo`](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/sudo) cookbook, it will be much easier for you to manage the sudoers file. as always, you can even test your cookbook that utilizes the `sudo` cookbook by using [`chefspec`](https://github.com/sethvargo/chefspec)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Chef has a feature to help with this, verifiers. You can set up the `verifies` on your sudoer template like this:

```
template '/etc/sudoers' do
  source 'whatever.erb
  verify 'visudo -c -f %{path}'
end
```

If visudo rejects the syntax, the tempfile will never get put in place and the converge will fail. Granted, this doesn't help if you have a syntactically valid but useless sudoers. You might consider using the `/etc/sudoers.d` structure as that keeps each bit at least somewhat separated and harder to accidentally whammy yourself.

Comment: I pushed a broken sudoers file with chef recently, that was quite a scare. Nice to see a verify step.

Comment: thanks for this answer! Unfortunately this fails for me (please see [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47690081/add-visudo-file-in-chef)). How did you get the verification to work?

Comment: (And you are missing a closing `'` after the source ;) )