# Adding a sudoers file in chef fails at verification

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, verification, sudoers

#### goal

I'm trying to add/edit a sudoers file in [Chef](https://chef.io).

After a lot of serach (and broken sudoers) I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37209997/should-we-really-use-chef-to-manage-the-sudoers-file) and [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37218297/7111561) seemed to be exactly what I am after.

---

#### My cookbook

So in my chef I added the following `visudo` cookbook:

The recipe: `~/chef-repo/cookbook/visudo/recipes/allowUpgrade.rb`

```
template '/etc/sudoers.d/allowUpgrade' do
    cookbook 'visudo'
    source 'allowUpgrade.erb'

    owner'root'
    group 'root'
    mode '0440'

    verify "visudo -c -f %{path}"
end
```

My template: `~/chef-repo/cookbooks/visudo/templates/allowUpgrade.erb`

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/upgrade
```

---

#### Template and verification works manually

When I put this line/file there manually using

```
sudo nano /etc/sudoers.d/allowUpgrade
```

(I know one shouldn't) and then verify it using

```
visudo -c -f /etc/sudoers.d/allowUpgrade
```

I get

```
/etc/sudoers.d/allowUpgrade: parsed OK
```

and it works meaning I can run

```
sudo upgrade
```

without beeing prompted for the sudo password.

---

#### Verification fails running Chef

However it is not working using Chef. I'm trying it first on the local machine using

```
sudo chef-client -z --runlist 'recipe[visudo::allowUpgrade]'
```

But I get this error

```
Error executing action `create` on resource 'template[/etc/sudoers.d/allowUpgrade]'

Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed
```

**Why is the verification failing in chef? What am I doing wrong?**

Here the complete error message

```
Recipe: visudo::allowUpgrade
  * template[/etc/sudoers.d/allowUpgrade] action create[2017-12-07T08:24:50+01:00] INFO: Processing template[/etc/sudoers.d/allowUpgrade] action create (visudo::                                         allowUpgrade line 7)


    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `create` on resource 'template[/etc/sudoers.d/allowUpgrade]'
    ================================================================================

    Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed
    ----------------------------------
    Proposed content for /etc/sudoers.d/allowUpgrade failed verification #<Chef::Resource::File::Verification:0x0000000004070c48>

    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /home/username/chef-repo/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/visudo/recipes/allowUpgrade.rb

      7: template '/etc/sudoers.d/allowUpgrade' do
      8:     owner'root'
      9:     group 'root'
     10:     mode '0440'
     11:     source 'allowUpgrade.erb'
     12:     verify 'visudo -c -f %{path}'
     13: end

    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in /home/username/chef-repo/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/visudo/recipes/allowUpgrade.rb:7:in `from_file'

    template("/etc/sudoers.d/allowUpgrade") do
      action [:create]
      default_guard_interpreter :default
      source "allowUpgrade.erb"
      declared_type :template
      cookbook_name "visudo"
      recipe_name "allowUpgrade"
      owner "root"
      group "root"
      mode "0440"
      verifications [#<Chef::Resource::File::Verification:0x0000000004070c48 @command_opts={},
          @command="visudo -c -f %{path}", @block=nil, @parent_resource=<template[/etc/sudoers.d/allowUpgrade] 
          @name: "/etc/sudoers.d/allowUpgrade" @before: nil @params: {} 
          @provider: nil @allowed_actions: [:nothing, :create, :delete, :touch, :create_if_missing] 
          @action: [:create] @updated: false @updated_by_last_action: false 
          @source_line: "/home/username/chef-repo/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/visudo/recipes/allowUpgrade.rb:7:in `from_file'" 
          @guard_interpreter: nil @default_guard_interpreter: :default 
          @elapsed_time: 0 @source: "allowUpgrade.erb" @cookbook: nil 
          @local: false @variables: {} @inline_helper_blocks: {} 
          @inline_helper_modules: [] @helper_modules: [] @declared_type: :template 
          @cookbook_name: "visudo" @recipe_name: "allowUpgrade" @owner: "root" @group: "root" @mode: "0440" 
          @verifications: [...] @path: "/etc/sudoers.d/allowUpgrade">>]
      path "/etc/sudoers.d/allowUpgrade"
    end
```

---

**Update**:

When I leave the verification out and just do

```
template '/etc/sudoers.d/allowUpgrade' do
    cookbook 'visudo'
    source 'allowUpgrade.erb'

    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
    mode '0440'

    verify { 1 == 1 }
end
```

The sudo is broken! In recovery mode and the root console I checked and it looks just the same as when I insert it manually (what works fine)?!

Comment: You should not have a space between NOPASSWD: and the command. I assume your console test doesn't test a rendered file at all. BTW there's a [`sudo` cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/sudo) with a provider to handle that which works fine

Comment: @Tensibai Thanks for the hint with the sudo cookbook. Since in the [manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers) they always have a space between `NOPASSWD:` and the command I thought it was obligatory. And this wouldn't explain why this works if I do it manually.

Comment: Do you create your cookbook from a windows box ? if the template has CRLF line endings and not LF that could be the problem.

Comment: I create them using `chef generate cookbook/recipe/template` on a chef-workstation on ubuntu server 16.04.2. I'm trying to run it local on this same machine. I'm editing my cookbooks in Brackets on Windows .. but I don't think this should be a problem, should it? Is there a way to find out what lineendings a file has?

Comment: Well, I've no idea if your editor allows it, atom show the line endings at bottom of the screen

Comment: @Tensibai Wow thanks a lot man! I would never have thought of the lineendings. I searched specific for that and found an Issue and a Plug-In which finally solved my problem (see my answer below)

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the help of [Tensibai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3627607/tensibai) here in the comments and the hint to `lineendings` I could finally solve this problem.

Indeed the issue was lineendings as noted in [this ancient Issue](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=188368)

I generated the cookbooks, recipes and templates on an Ubuntu Server 16.04 but do all m editing on the repository in [Brackets.io](https://Brackets.io) on Windows.

This made template (and other) files have `CRLF` instead of `LF` lineendings because Brackets seems to use automatically the lineendings of the OS it is running on. This ofcourse made the `/etc/sudoers.d/allowUpgrade` file brake the `sudoers` because it has to end in a new line.

After some research I found this was an [old known Issue](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/10106) and could be solved by [the Plug-In Newline](https://github.com/LonelyStorm/brackets-newline).

[image]

After installing this Plug-In indeed I could see that the file had `CRLF` lineendings.

[image]

I switched it to `LF` thanks to the Plug-In by clicking on the `CRLF`. Now my cookbook runs as expected and I'm able to run

```
sudo upgrade
```

without beeng prompted for the password - meaning it works.